# Interpretation of statistical outcomes: studies of "Moral Hypocrisy"

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, p-value

I am dealing with the studies of C.Daniel Batson, who provided several studies and experiments to reveal moral hypocrisy. I think that I understand the basic idea of his theory, however I am not really able to interpret his statistical outcomes.

I do not know if some of you have access to the full text, but the study is listed under the title:

**In a very different voice: Unmasking moral hypocrisy.** Batson, C. Daniel; Kobrynowicz, Diane; Dinnerstein, Jessica L.; Kampf, Hannah C.; Wilson, Angela D. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, Vol 72(6), Jun 1997, 1335-1348

However, I will provide some relevant excerpts in the form of pictures for better comprehension towards my question.

First excerpts:

[image]

In this part Batson et. al. present the results and compare them through the previously measured responsibility measures indexes. The confusing part starts from the yellow lined part. I do not really understand meaning of coding?

Furthermore, he mentions that only one of this applied measures correlated with the results and provides the result **r(18)=0,39, p< 0,05** (blue lined). This is the core of my real problem. First of all I do not really understand what r(18) has to mean? I think it has to be linked to a normal distribution? Moreover, I have no idea how to read the 0,39 in a clear way. Does it mean that 39% of the results actually are coherent with the previously applied measurement indexes of moral responsibility? In the end I also struggle to interpret the p-vale of 0,05. Does it mean that the value (0,39) would be theoretically rejected, if it would be below 0,05?

To demonstrate the full results I also provide you the second excerpt:

[image]

I really struggling to understand this notations. The worst thing is that it is not explained in the whole text, how these numbers have to be interpreted. I also read several other psychological texts, which have very similar expressions.

I hope that my question is somehow understandable, because it is very difficult to ask this question, if nobody has an access to the full text. I would be extremely grateful, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The outcomes were "assigned other to positive" or "assigned self to positive" but these need to be recorded in some convenient way. Indeed, some packages will require you to record these as numbers before putting them into some statistical analysis. Whether required or simply for convenience, the transformation from those text categories to some numerical values on which analysis can be done is often called "coding".
2. No doubt $r$ means the statistic being tested for significance is the [*correlation coefficient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient), $r$ (The null presumably being that the population correlation is $0$ against the two tailed alternative that it differs from $0$).

   Indeed, the word "correlation" occurs in the sentence you highlighted in green. While it wasn't mentioned in the previous sentence, $r$ is a common symbol for the sample correlation, and both sentences mention the statistic $r$.

   The $18$ presumably refers to the degrees of freedom in the [t-test for correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution).

   (It's annoying to me the degree to which authors - typically encouraged or even forced by journal editors or even journal standards - tend to abbreviate the statistics information so much that the reader is forced to make guesses at what they decided to do. How many more characters would it take to make it explicit in context?)

   However in this case, from your second image, we do see the confirmation that it is indeed correlation that is being examined:

   [image]

   So all those numbers in your second excerpt are correlations and presumably would be interpreted as correlations would generally be understood.